# Proc Sql: running total

Tags: sas

I have below data and I'm creating running total -

```
data test;
input id$ year qtr sales;
cards;
a 2015 1 100
a 2015 2 2200
a 2015 3 100
a 2015 4 100
b 2015 1 10
b 2015 2 10


;run;

proc sql;
select a.id,a.year,a.qtr,a.sales,sum(a.sales) as running_tot
from test a,test b where a.id=b.id and a.year=b.year and a.qtr >= b.qtr
group by 1,2,3,4;
quit;
```

But the result is not correct, but if I make sales 100 instead of 2200, result is coming correct?

Answer (score 1):

You are summing the wrong copy of the SALES variable.

```
select a.id,a.year,a.qtr,a.sales
     , sum(b.sales) as running_tot
  from test a 
  left join test b on a.id=b.id and a.year=b.year and a.qtr >= b.qtr
  group by 1,2,3,4
;
```

Of course it is easier to just use a data step.

```
data want ;
  set test;
  by id year qtr;
  if first.year then running_tot=0;
  running_tot + sales;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you Tom for the quick reply :). Can you please brief, whats the difference if I take a.sales instead of b.sales. I'm a bit confused in that. Once again thanks for your help.

Comment: If you use A.SALES  the result is the number of quarters times this quarter's value since A.SALES does not change for all of the result rows that you are summing over.  So if your quarterly sales were 1,2,3,4, then your results would be 1,4,9,16.

Answer (score 0):

The `A` alias is acting as supplier of the guard value that limits how many `B` rows are joined to it.  Thus if you `SUM(A.SALES)` you are essentially multiplying the sales of the guard row by the number of B rows matched to it by `A.qtr >= B.qtr`

The `group by 1,2,3,4` can really be `group by 1,2,3`. Do you see why ?

The 4<sup>th</sup> column, `A.sales` in conjunction with the `where` criteria leads to the case that `A.sales` will always be the same for group 1,2,3 and thus unnecessary.

Examine the ungrouped results for a better understanding:

```
proc sql;
  create table work.result_ungrouped as
  select 
    a.id,
    a.year,
    a.qtr as a_qtr,
    a.sales as a_sales,
    b.qtr as b_qtr,
    b.sales as b_sales
from 
    test a, 
    test b
where 
    a.id = b.id and 
    a.year = b.year and
    a.qtr >= b.qtr    
;
quit;
```

Thus, the correct results is delivered by `SUM(B.sales)` because those are subordinate (or detail) values within the group being aggregated.