# operations with reference cells proc sql?

Tags: sas

I have this table, call it "pre_report":

| initial_balance | deposit | withdrawal | final_balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 50 | 0 | . |
| 1000 | 0 | 25 | . |
| 1000 | 45 | 0 | . |
| 1000 | 30 | 0 | . |
| 1000 | 0 | 70 | . |

I want create a code in SAS that updates the "final_balance" field, the "deposit" field adds to the balance and "withdrawal" subtracts, but at the same time changes the values of the "initial_balance" field, in such a way that my desired output be this:

| initial_balance | deposit | withdrawal | final_balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 50 | 0 | 1050 |
| 1050 | 0 | 25 | 1025 |
| 1025 | 45 | 0 | 1070 |
| 1070 | 30 | 0 | 1100 |
| 1100 | 0 | 70 | 1030 |

I try this:

```
proc sql;
    select initial_balance format=dollar32.2,
           deposit format=dollar32.2,
           withdrawal format=dollar32.2,
           sum(initial_balance,deposit,-withdrawal) as final_balance,
           calculated final_balance as initial_balance
    from work.pre_report;   
quit;
```

But it doesn't work properly. This code create two fields "final_balance" and "initial_balance" but both with the sames quantity.

**code for creating "pre_report" table**

```
data work.pre_report;
input initial_balance deposit withdrawal final_balance;;
datalines;
1000 50 0 .
1000 0 25 .
1000 45 0 .
1000 30 0 .
1000 0 70 .
run;
```

I would really appreciate if you help me.

Comment: `proc sql` is not the best way to do this.  A data step with `retain` is much more efficient.

Comment: It's school work and they asked me to do it with SQL language, and I learned SQL within SAS.

Comment: This appears to do what you want, but you'll need to work out what it's saying. You basically need to do a running total. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54939511/proc-sql-running-total. But it's important to note: there is no indicator in your data of what order this needs to be summed in. There's no month or year

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68606584/query-for-a-financial-balance-with-a-proc-sql-in-sas Nick.McDermaid this is my original question. I resolve only a part of my problem

Comment: Are you taking a class in how to use SAS?  Or are you trying to learn SQL?  If the former use a data step.  If the later then SAS is not the right SQL implementation for this type of problem as it does not support modern SQL syntax enhancements that would make it possible.